# Is it possible to upload a file in Symfony2 without referring to entity's or using Doctrine?

Tags: symfony

I'm building a web application that displays specific data to the customers of my client. The client wants to populate the application with data via a CSV file. So he needs to be able to upload the file to the server, and the application places the CSV data in to the database.

I am using `Ddeboer/DataImport` bundle and have managed to get it to work with a CSV file already placed on the server. The trick now is to get the CSV file on to the server in the first place.

Because I want the file to be directly sent to the server, and that it won't be associated to any other records held on the database, I feel there is absolutely no need to use Doctrine at all. However, the documentation that I've encountered suggest that you should only upload files to the server via Doctrine/Database. Surely this can't be the case?

Is there a simple way of just uploading the file to a designated folder on the server? No bells or whistles, just a pure file upload in Symfony2.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

Comment: @Cerad if you put this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is.  The cookbook only contains a doctrine based entry but it has a link to the file form type.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html